# Problems running boot sector on QEMU

Tags: assembly, x86, boot, qemu, osdev

I am working on an operating system. I am developing on an AMD64 system, compiling with NASM. I have a boot sector that compiles but won't run on QEMU. I checked the registers after the bootup to see if QEMU is actually loading and executing the boot sector. This is what I noticed:

- It loads the boot sector, checks the memory address `0x7c00` and shows the boot sector code
- No execution seems to be happening, all the registers are set to `0xf000ff53` despite the boot sector setting them to zero

The boot sector code that I have specifically set registers to zero then halts the execution. However, the QEMU registers don't reflect this. Could anyone help me out on getting the code working? Is there something wrong with QEMU? Here is the code for the boot sector:

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16

cli
xor ax, ax

mov bx, ax
mov cx, ax
mov dx, ax

hlt

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

How do I solve this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks okay, how are you checking the registers?

Comment: Looks fine indeed, maybe the CPU resumed for some reason. Does the problem still exist if you do some busy loop instead? Try replacing `hlt` by `jmp $`

Comment: @Nax unless he gets a non-maskable interrupts (not likely in this situation with QEMU). _HLT_ will halt the CPU until the next interrupt, however he has already issued a _CLI_. So likely not the source of problems. Usually I do something like `cli` `hltloop: hlt` `jmp hltloop`.

Comment: `0xf000ff53` seems like a BIOS address, so I wonder if the bootsector has even run and it was stopped by the debugger at the beginning of BIOS execution and not the beginning of the boot sector. Did you set a breakpoint using `break *0x7c00` (I assume remote debugging with GDB) and use the continue (`c`) command to execute until it reached the first breakpoint of your bootloader? Once you hit the beginning of your boot loader then step through the instructions that zero the registers and see if they look correct.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I don't know QEMU much (I prefer bochs) but I suppose some bad configuration may generate hardware-fault NMI. You're right about the `hlt` loop, it's the safest way to ignore NMIs while halting the CPU.

Bochs, when compiled with debug support, always sets a breakpoint in the BIOS. This is a very helpful feature, very useful to debug nasty triple faults. QEMU probably supports that as well. OP, do you have a debugger attached ? (either built-in or as a GDB stub)

Comment: @user3259743  I don't know if this is possible, but can you edit your question to tell us what commands you are using to assemble/link/generate your disk image and what debugger you are using, and what commands you use to launch the debugger and QEMU? As well what commands you use to view the registers. If none of that is possible I'd at least be willing to entertain a screenshot of the debugger as it is when it is displaying `0xf000ff53`

Comment: I really hope you are not using _QEMU_ with the `-kernel` option to load your bootloader.